# Python/Pandas TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, list, pandas, datetime

This is not a duplicate question, or at least I don't think so.

When I try to run this code snippet of just two lines:

```
import pandas as pd

mydates = pd.date_range('2010-01-22', '2010-01-26')
```

On trying the foll:

```
In [16]:import pandas as pd

In [17]:mydates = pd.date_range('2010-01-22', '2010-01-26')
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I get the below error after trying on both 2.7 and 3.6

```
File "<ipython-input-17-ef49b611e028>", line 1, in <module>
        mydates = pd.date_range('2010-01-22', '2010-01-26')

    TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I tried to replicate this in Python 3.6 in the standard shell (not iPython), and `mydates = pd.date_range('2010-01-22', '2010-01-26')` seemed to work just fine - have you tried this in a standard Python shell as well, and does it work okay there?

Comment: I messed up kind of what piRSquared described, then I tried to isolate my problem by just running those 2 lines, but I didn't restart the kernel..
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like python thinks `pd.date_range` is a list and that you're trying to call it.  You may have accidentally done something like this:

```
pd.date_range = []
```

Check to see what its type is

```
type(pd.date_range)

list
```

***solution***

Restart your kernel.

Comment: @MadHatter it happens sometimes!

Answer (score 0):

Install pandas!

*if working on Jupyter notebook:
Use **conda install pandas**
else:
Use **pip install pandas***

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thank you for your time answering this question. Can you please give more details about your solution? Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Please install the panda's library again. Maybe this will help you to sort out your problem

To install panda's library,

**conda install pandas**